# Визуальный редактор

Tags: jquery, javascript, редактор

Нужен визуальный редактор. Простенький без особых излишеств. Хватит тех же кнопок как у ХэшКод'а. Желательно, без особой геморойности в установке. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ck-editor](http://ckeditor.com/)
[mce-editor](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Халявко, у обоих есть преимущества и недостатки. У обоих есть расширенные, средние и минимальные версии. Со вторым проще, если требуется загрузка файлов. Первый лучше распознает копипасту из Ворда. Это вкратце.

Comment: Чего то mce сайт не нашел. Киньте сылочку :)

Comment: там ссылка прямо на названии. =/

Comment: сначала то не было :).

Comment: "Fatahan (5 минут назад)" пять минут назад уже была. ~^__^~

Comment: Когда я открыл не было ^^^_^^^

Answer (score 0):

По моему самый легкий: [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)